# Can I add a variable value to a passed function parameter in php?

Tags: php

I have the following variable:

```
$argument = 'blue widget';
```

Which I pass in the following function:

```
widgets($argument);
```

The widgets function has two variables in it:

```
$price = '5';
$demand ='low';
```

My questions is how can I do the following:

```
 $argument = 'blue widget'.$price.' a bunch of other text';
 widgets($argument);
 //now have function output argument with the $price variable inserted where I wanted.
```

- I don't want to pass $price to the function
- price is made available once inside the function

Is there any sound way I can do this or do I need to rethink my design?

Comment: "I don't want to pass $price to the function" Why that, because it seems to be the default way to accomplish that…

Comment: Wait.  You said `$price` was *inside* the `widgets` function.  How can you pass `widgets` `$price` if it only exists inside `widgets`?

Comment: Rather I want to pass a variable (say $get_price) that once inside the function I can then set to price.

Comment: @absentx: What do you want to do exactly?  You mean something like `function foo(&$var){ $var = 123; } $test = 0; foo($test); echo $test; //123`?

Comment: Not quite, I just have a variable that is declared outside of the function `$argument ='this is neat'.$value.'done';` but what I want to put in `$value` will not become available until `$argument` is passed to the function, because I am calling some config files once in the function, meaning what i want $value to become, is only available inside the function. The str replace method below works wonderfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head, there are two ways to do this:

1. Pass in two arguments

   ```
   widget($initText, $finalText) {
       echo $initText . $price . $finalText;
   }
   ```
2. Use a placeholder

   ```
   $placeholder = "blue widget {price} a bunch of other text";   
   widget($placeholder);

   function widget($placeholder) {
        echo str_replace('{price}',$price,$placeholder);
   }
   // within the function, use str_replace
   ```

Here's an example: http://codepad.org/Tme2Blu8

Comment: Rocket, thank you. I could not get the code tags to work for some reason.

Comment: When in a list, you need to indent code tags with 8 spaces instead of 4.  It's weird.

Comment: Had very much considered the place holder and str replace, wanted to see if others considered that a sound solution.

Comment: Expanded the function as well for completeness. @absentx: String replace is quite common place when dealing with placeholders.

Answer (score 3):

Use some sort of placeholder, then replace it within your function:

```
widgets('blue widget ##price## a bunch of other text');

function widgets($argument) {
    $price = '5';
    $demand = 'low';

    $argument = str_replace('##price##', $price, $argument);
}
```

See it here in action: http://viper-7.com/zlXXkN

Answer (score 2):

Create a placeholder for your variables like this:

```
$argument = 'blue widget :price a bunch of other text';
```

in your `widget()` function, use a dictionary array and `str_replace()` to get your result string:

```
function widgets($argument) {
  $dict = array(
    ':price'  => '20',
    ':demand' => 'low',
  );
  $argument = str_replace(array_keys($dict), array_values($dict), $argument);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage `preg_replace_callback`. By using this method, we can easily use the captured values as a lookup to determine what their replacement should be. If we come across an invalid key, perhaps the cause of a typo, we can respond to this as well.

```
// This will be called for every match ( $m represents the match )
function replacer ( $m ) {
    // Construct our array of replacements
    $data = array( "price" => 5, "demand" => "low" );
    // Return the proper value, or indicate key was invalid
    return isset( $data[ $m[1] ] ) ? $data[ $m[1] ] : "{invalid key}" ;
}

// Our main widget function which takes a string with placeholders
function widget ( $arguments ) {
    // Performs a lookup on anything between { and }
    echo preg_replace_callback( "/{(.+?)}/", 'replacer', $arguments );
}

// The price is 5 and {invalid key} demand is low.
widget( "The price is {price} and {nothing} demand is {demand}." );
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/9HvmQA6T

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Use global inside your function.

```
$global_var = 'a';
foo($global_var);

function foo($var){
    global $global_var;

    $global_var = 'some modifications'.$var;
}
```

Comment: I'm so confused by this.  You're passing `foo` `global_var` but ALSO making it global?  Inside `foo`, `$global_var === $var`.

Comment: Of course it could be done with simply `$global_var .= 'something';` but OP wanted to pass it as variable. That's why I did these strange things.

Comment: That's what references are for :-P  `function foo(&$var){ $var .= 'test'; } $test = '123'; foo($test);  echo $test; //123test`

Answer (score -1):

Consider changing the argument and then returning it from your widget function rather than simply changing it within the function. It will be more clear to people reading your code that $argument is being modified without having to read the function as well.

```
$argument = widget($argument);

function widget($argument) {
    // get $price;
    return $argument . $price;
}
```